# Generally speaking, how long does it take for the new podcast to be released to the blog?

Tags: support, blog, podcast

I recently just started listening to the podcast again and was wondering what the typical lag time between the live podcast and the recorded version being posted on the blog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there have been 3 live sessions so far.

The first session was on [**May 31st**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/512/2011/5/31), and the corresponding blog post got posted on [**June 1st**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/se-podcast-06/).

The next live recording happened on [**June 7th**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/512/2011/6/7), and the blog post came out on [**June 8th**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/se-podcast-07/).

The latest one was yesterday, [**June 15th**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/512/2011/6/15). The blog post will probably come out later today, as it appears that the average time difference between the recording session and the blog post is **one day**. Note that in both of the previous postings, the blog post came out late in the day (as determined from when chat feeds posted it), so it is most likely to come out near the end of the day for today's as well.

---

The blog post [came out today](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/se-podcast-08/). Even earlier than the other ones in terms of time-of-day, but it's out now nonetheless.

Comment: Podcast is already on sound cloud by the way.